# how to extract data from xml having multiple nodes which are same under a parent node into a table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a xml like

```
<list of roleids>
  <roleid> 1 </roleid>
  <roleid> 2 </roleid>
  <roleid> 3 </roleid>
  <roleid> 4 </roleid>
</list of Roleids>
```

I want the roleid values in a table with column RoleID

I have tried with the below query but i am not getting the expected output

```
 declare @ListOfRoleID XML
    set @ListOfRoleID = 
    '<list>
    <roleid>1</roleid>
    <roleid>2</roleid>
    </list>'

    DECLARE @RoleIDList TABLE (RoleID int)

    INSERT INTO @RoleIDList(RoleID)

    SELECT X1.value('(roleid)[1]','INT') as roleid
    from @ListOfRoleID.nodes('/list') as ListOfRoleID(x)
    CROSS APPLY @RoleIDList.nodes('/list') AS ListOfRoleID1 (X1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to project `.nodes('/list/roleid')`, which will create one row per roleid. Then extract the value. No need for cross apply. See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20684):

```
 declare @ListOfRoleID XML = '<list>
    <roleid>1</roleid>
    <roleid>2</roleid>
    <roleid>3</roleid>
    </list>';

SELECT x.value('.','INT') as roleid
from @ListOfRoleID.nodes('/list/roleid') as ListOfRoleID(x);
```